# SEO - Sendo penalizado pelo Google Fonts

Tags: google, seo, pagespeed-insights

Estou utilizando uma fonte que está no Google Fonts em meu site e estou importando através do css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,800,900');
```

O problema é que o [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) notifica a seguinte informação:

**Garanta que o texto continue visível durante o carregamento da webfont**

Use o recurso CSS de exibição de fonte para garantir que o texto possa ser visto pelo usuário enquanto as webfonts são carregadas.

Abaixo da notificação, são listadas todas as especificações de fonte que estou importando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já teve este problema?

Sabe como isto pode ser ajustado?

Estou com essa notificação em vários sites que utilizam o Google Fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muito provavelmente é por causa dos `FOUT`, `FOIT`, `FOFT`, vc pode ler sobre eles aqui https://css-tricks.com/fout-foit-foft/

Repare que vc está importando 4MB de fontes....

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como o site deve estar carregando muito coisa em um determinado momento o site pode aparentar estar sem fontes, ou as fontes podem "piscar", demorando para aparecer pro usuário. No artigo acima tem os detalhes.

Pode ser que se vc adicionar a propriedade `font-display` para tentar contornar isso adicionando um "*fallback*" com uma fonte local caso a sua `@font-face` demore a carregar. Para isso te indico esse outro artigo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display

No seu CSS basicamente vc teria um código desse tipo. Repare no formato das fontes `.ttf`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ExampleFont;
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,800,900') format('woff2'),
       url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,800,900') format('truetype'),
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: fallback;
}
```

Leia isso tb é importante https://css-tricks.com/dont-just-copy-the-font-face-out-of-google-fonts-urls/

Comment: Complementando, `font-display` é uma propriedade atualmente em [fase experimental](https://caniuse.com/#search=font-display), não suporta alguns navegadores antigos e mobiles, mas servira como medida paliativa para o Pagespeed parar de reclamar... haha

Comment: Percebi que agora, no Google Fonts, quando importo uma fonte, no final ele vem com a opção de font-display, porém vem com a propriedade &display=swap; sabe dizer qual é a diferença entre fallback e swap?

Comment: @MaurícioKrüger a documentação não explica bem o que é cada um, mas aqui tem vai uma explicação um pouco melhor. **swap:** Instrui o navegador a usar a fonte de fallback para exibir o texto até que a fonte personalizada tenha sido totalmente baixada. Isso também é conhecido como "flash de texto não estilizado" ou FOUT.
**fallback:** O navegador ocultará o texto por cerca de 100 ms e, se a fonte ainda não tiver sido baixada, usará o texto de fallback. Ele irá trocar para a nova fonte após o download, mas somente durante um curto período de troca (provavelmente 3 segundos).

Comment: Outras duas fontes para vc aprofundar no assunto https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-display/ e aqui tb https://css-tricks.com/font-display-masses/ eu mesmo ainda tenho que ler mais sobre isso rss, tem coisa que a gente vê uma vez e depois vai esquecendo...